# How to change search view home up arrow or its color in android?

Tags: android, xml

[image]    // change arrow color or image show in image how to change

```
final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
                                  upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.app_theme_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                                  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {`enter code here`
                                    mActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow));
                                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Change Icon like this....

Hope this helps...

```
menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).setOnActionExpandListener(this); 
    // Your Activity/Fragment must implement the MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener interface

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
        getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.uvweb_logo);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: i set icon on that but i want to remove change or color change or icon change  of that arrow